# Django Project Serving Static Files With Several Apps

Tags: python, css, django, view, django-staticfiles

I have the following structure in my Django project. As you can see, there is one app called "blog" as well as the main app that is eponymous with the project itself.

[image]

The problem I am having has to do with serving static files from the `static` directory of the main project. The `blog` app has its own `static` directory and those files are served properly (when the pertinent URL routes are traversed).

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, what is the best practice of serving static files when dealing with multiple apps? Is it prudent to dump all styles and scripts into a common `static` directory in the root of the project or is it better to keep things entirely separated from app to app?

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "django_by_example_blog", "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="base.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
]
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Home | Triangle</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "css/animate.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="{% static "css/lightbox.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="{% static "css/main.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "css/responsive.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="{% static "js/html5shiv.js" %}></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/respond.min.js" %}"></script>
    <![endif]-->       
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "images/ico/favicon.ico" %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="{% static "images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="{% static "images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="{% static "images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="{% static "images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" %}">
</head><!--/head-->

<body>
```

Answer (score 3):

STATIC_ROOT specifies the folder into which all static files will be dumped when you run the `collectstatic` command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You seem to have specified one of your app's static folder as the static_root.

It would be preferable to give another folder for holding all your static files.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

when you run the `collectstatic` command it would collect all your static files and place them into the `STATIC_ROOT` folder.

Although, while running in `DEBUG=True` you needn't worry about any of this.
Django will serve all the static content (including from within individual apps), but in a production environment this is not recommended and it would be the job of the web server to serve static content.

EDIT:

You also need to specify in your base urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: The problem is that this does not seem to be working. When I specify `STATIC_ROOT` the same way you did, my CSS files are still not found. Is there a way to test this?
Also, am I understanding correctly that `collectstatic` will look at static folder inside every app and physically move them into whatever is specified by `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: Yes, collectstatic will look at all static folders inside each app and move them to the folder specified by static_root.

In your browser check the url for the css files in the source, and see if it lines up with what is expected?

Comment: URLs come out like this `"/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"` but they cannot be found. I am not sure at this point what Django treats as the root point of the application.

Comment: the only file I can find is `static/css/blog.css` but this one is located inside the `blog` app's `static` directory. It seems that somehow Django is grabbing that one?

Comment: Where is the bootstrap file placed?

Did you make the changes for static_root and urls.py?

Comment: The bootstrap file is currently inside `project/static` - the root directory. I have made the following changes: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 2):

"Dumping all styles and scripts into a common static directory" is exactly what the `collectstatic` command does. You should run that, and configure your server to serve the files from there.

First though you should set your STATIC_ROOT setting to point to that common directory, rather than inside your app.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Erm, about what in particular?

Comment: Where to run the command, how to fix the code. I would not be asking this if I was throughly knowledgeable about the framework.